# custom metric using ROCR package in caret

Tags: r, r-caret, roc

here is minimal example of my problem. I want to use the Recall as a performance metric in caret

```
library(caret)
set.seed(1234)

x <- matrix(rnorm(10),nrow=5,ncol=2 )
y <- factor(c("y","n","y","y","n"))


my.metric <- function (data,
                   lev = NULL,
                   model = NULL) {
  out <- ROCR::performance(ROCR::prediction(data$pred,       as.numeric(data$obs)-1,"rec"))
  names(out) <- "REC"
  out
 }

 myControl <- trainControl(summaryFunction = my.metric, method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=2)

 fit <- train(y=y,x=x, metric = "REC",method="gbm", trControl = myControl)
```

however, I get this error

```
 Error in ROCR::prediction(data$pred, as.numeric(data$obs) - 1, "rec") : 
 Format of predictions is invalid.
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this package in a while but based on the example in `?prediction`, you need to pass the class probabilities (and the `train` doesn't generate these unless you use the option `classProbs = TRUE` in `trainControl`) in for the argument `predictions`. Once you have done that, use the proper column of `data` as an input to the `prediction` function.

Also, you  should read [the paper](http://bioinformatics.oxfordjournals.org/cgi/content/abstract/21/20/3940) on the subject because I think you need an extra call to `performance` to get recall.

Max

Comment: I added `classProbs = TRUE` and still get this error